# input from jquery modal doesn't reach server side

Tags: jquery, input, dialog, server

Here is the Java Script . The value I am trying to pass is txtApplicationDate

But the value doesn't reach server side 
Any help will be appreciated

```
function ShowApplicationAttestationDialog() {
$("#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_LoanMasterBodyContent_txtApplicationDate").datepicker();
$("#ApplicationDateDialog").dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Application Attestation",
    buttons: [
                 {
                     text: "Save",
                     click: function () {

                         $(this).dialog("close");
                         if ($("#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_LoanMasterBodyContent_txtApplicationDate").val().length > 0)
                         {
                             $("#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_LoanMasterBodyContent_btnContinue").click();
                         }
                     }
                 }
    ]

});

$("#ApplicationDateDialog").dialog("open");
return false;
```

}

Here is the markup. This is an aspx with an update panel in it.
On Page load , I am adding onclick attribute to the submit button to invoke the above mentioned  javascript function

```
    <div id="ApplicationDateDialog" style="display: none;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span>The application date identified for this loan is :</span></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox id="txtApplicationDate" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cbxConfirm" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><span style="color: red;">I confirm this is the date the  six points of data required to take a loan aplication was received.</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where is your aspx , js and vb?

Answer (score 0):

Change code and make access it as
from $("#ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_LoanMasterBodyContent_txtApplicationDate")

to

**$('#<%=txtApplicationDate.ClientID%>').val()** and

**$('#<%=cbxConfirm.ClientID%>').val()** . You will get values to access in jQuery.

Comment: I will have to pass the user input to the server side. I am not setting the control value programatically. I can see the user input validated on the client side but on the server side button click handler, it disappears .